How to make procedural crackles with lines starting on edges?
I'm trying to generate procedural crackles. Every tutorials I've found about that are using Voronoi with distance to edge. The probem with Voronoi is the crackles are generated following this pattern where each line starts from a summit:

Instead of that, I would like the lines to start on edges like in this picture:


Could you edit the question and share a sketch how precisely it would need to look on a mesh?

Yes I admit it was a bit confused because when a line starts on an edge it creates a summit of course. What I want is to have more "T" like intersections and less "Y" like.

Voronoi + Brick Texture
To achieve some interesting results, a starting point could be trying to slant  cells of brick texture.
I tried 'wrapping' a Brick texture on the distance and position of one or more Voronoi Textures to distort it.
The results are a step in the right direction but not as geometric as your example.


Blender 4.3.1


To address the problem expressed in text ignoring the sketch where there are additional direction changes in the lines you could add some lines made with wave texture and then rotated randomly per voronoi cell using the "color" of same voronoi, but in F1 mode for the rotation:

Not sure if you wanted the direction changes as well. It's possible to add them as well:

This is only similar to the sketch though, because one would probably need to draw lines individually with some probability for them to change direction and then terminate when they encounter another line, or something like that. It might be possible to create a more precise pattern in geometry nodes.

Dour comments aside, your revision is good.  I will upvote it.

Still not perfect though. It will not replicate the pattern one could draw by hand precisely.

Another method using the shader editor is to create two groups of voronoi cells. One voronoi cell group is 3x bigger than another cell group of voronoi.
The intersections of the smaller voronoi cells will partly be covered by the larger cells, and they will fill the 'mortar' or spaces in between the larger fragments.


Blender 4.3.1


Your answers don't really match the sketch of desired result at all.

This question does not have an answer exactly like the sketch, yet.
